# In R plotly is there a vertical line symbol that is not centered at the data point?

Tags: r, plotly

Among the various line types available for `mode='markers'` in a `plotly` scatterplot is `marker=list(symbol='line-ns-open')`.  This can be used to easily make vertical line segments centered at a specific `y` value.  I could not find a line type that is vertical that uses the data point as its base instead of its center.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Shapes don't allow for custom hover text and don't inherit grouping of data as `add_trace` and `plot_ly` do.  Shapes also seem to take up a lot of space when creating a hundred `space` objects.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a symbol that will do it, but you could use `mode = "lines"` in a for loop as done [here](http://moderndata.plot.ly/gantt-charts-in-r-using-plotly/).  I adapted the following from the previous link:

```
x <- c(1:20, 1:20)
y <- (1:40) 
color <- rep(c(team1 = "blue", team2 = "red"), each = 20)

library(plotly)

p <- plot_ly()

for(i in seq_along(x)){
p <- add_trace(p,
    x = c(x[i], x[i]),
    y = c(y[i], y[i] + 1L), # make your lines as tall as you'd like
    group = names(color[i]),
    mode = "lines",
    line = list(width = 1L, color = color[i]),
    showlegend = FALSE,
    evaluate = TRUE)}

p
```

Comment: I think the output will be fine but I think there is extra overhead in creating a hundred traces in my case.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Definitely extra overhead and larger output than if there were an appropriate symbol type for this.  For now, this is the best I was able to come up with to get the desired output.